# Cancel Reservation on JAVA JSP

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I have a simple web application in which I can book a room. If I go on my booked room I have the list of the room that I have booked.
Now I want to implement a simple button to delete a specific reservation.
In my DB I have:

> hotel_booking

with this parameters:

> cid, cname, email, arrival_date, departure_date, person, room, type_room,comment, status, uid.

Now I have created:

> cancel.jsp

And this is the code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
 <%
int id;
int person;
int room;



id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
//  out.println(id);
String cname  = request.getParameter("cname");
 // out.println(cname);
String email  = request.getParameter("email");
String arrival  = request.getParameter("arrival_date");
String departure  = request.getParameter("departure_date");
person = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("person"));
room = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("room"));

  String type_room = request.getParameter("type_room");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");

String del = "delete from hotel_booking where id='" + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")) + "'AND cname='" + request.getParameter(cname) + "'AND emal='" + request.getParameter(email) + "'";

java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();

int rowNum = st.executeUpdate(del);
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
st.close();
%>
```

while in my booked.jsp I have inserted this form for the cancel button:

```
<form action='cancel.jsp'>
             <input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'>
             <input type="hidden" name="id" value=\""+id+"\">
            </form>
           </div>
```

But I receive this kind of error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/cancel.jsp] at line [10]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/cancel.jsp] at line [10]

7: 
8: 
9: 
10: id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
11: //  out.println(id);
12: String cname  = request.getParameter("cname");
13:  // out.println(cname);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:593)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:482)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\""+id+"\""
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    org.apache.jsp.cancel_jsp._jspService(cancel_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

How can I solve? Every time that someone books a room, in my DB automatically cid parameter is increased by one.
Thanks all of you

Comment: If it was me, I wouldn't 'delete' this. I think it would useful to know that booking was commenced but not completed.

Comment: `value="<%= id %>">` or such (`value="${id}">`), but some answers might elaborate on really nice coding.

Comment: @strawberry do you think that is better not delete a reservation?

Comment: In the real world, data is rarely deleted. It's "soft deleted", meaning it's marked as removed instead of really being removed.

Comment: If I didn't think so, I wouldn't have said so :-$

Comment: How can i do so for a soft deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<form action='cancel.jsp'>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=id%>">
 <input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'>             
 </form>
</div>
```

since the value for id is passed as "\""+id+"\"". But in your code you tried to Parse the string which contains non numeric values as Integer throws NumberFormatException.